# Optimizing the method block

Tags: java, selenium, optimization

I'm writing a Selenium code in Java. And below is one of the methods block.

```
private static void getPaceNumber(WebDriver chromeDriver, String dBName, XSSFSheet paceSheet, String pubName, int i,
        XSSFCell cell, XSSFWorkbook workbook) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("DBID is " + dBName + " and fpn is " + pubName);
    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    int defaultHeight = paceSheet.getRow(0).getHeight();
    cell = paceSheet.getRow(i).createCell(1);
    paceSheet.getRow(i).setHeight((short) (defaultHeight * 2));
    if (dBName == "" || dBName.equals("null")) {
        System.out.println("Null Block");
        cell.setCellValue("N/A");
    } else {
        chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/b/b/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/textarea"))
                .sendKeys("\"" + dBName + "\"");
        chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/b/b/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/input[1]")).click();
        // Thread.sleep(500L);
        System.out.println("entered second block");
        List<WebElement> pace = chromeDriver
                .findElements(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input[1]"));
        int paceSize = pace.size();
        System.out.println("pace size is " + paceSize);
        int pubPaceNumber = 0;
        int dbPaceNumber;
        if (paceSize >= 1) {
            dbPaceNumber = Integer.parseInt(
                    chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input[1]"))
                            .getAttribute("value"));
            chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='searchPublication']")).click();
            chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/b/b/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/textarea"))
                    .sendKeys("\"" + pubName + "\"");
            chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/b/b/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/input[1]")).click();

            int paceSizse = chromeDriver
                    .findElements(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input[1]")).size();
            if (paceSizse >= 1) {
                pubPaceNumber = Integer.parseInt(
                        chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input[1]"))
                                .getAttribute("value"));
            } else {
                List<WebElement> table = chromeDriver
                        .findElements(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td/b"));
                int tabSize = table.size();
                System.out.println("Tab size is " + tabSize);
                if (tabSize == 1) {
                    chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='searchPublication']")).click();
                    chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/b/b/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/textarea"))
                            .sendKeys("\"" + pubName + "\"");
                    chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/b/b/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/input[1]"))
                            .click();
                    List<WebElement> paceWithFPN = chromeDriver
                            .findElements(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input[1]"));
                    int paceWithFPNSize = paceWithFPN.size();
                    if (paceWithFPNSize >= 1) {

                        cell.setCellValue("N/A");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue("N/A");
                    }

                } else {
                    cell.setCellValue("N/A");
                }

            }

            if (dbPaceNumber == pubPaceNumber) {
                cell.setCellValue(dbPaceNumber);
            } else {

                cell.setCellValue(dbPaceNumber + "\n" + pubPaceNumber);
                style.setWrapText(true);
                style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
            }

        } else {
            List<WebElement> table = chromeDriver
                    .findElements(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td/b"));
            int tabSize = table.size();
            System.out.println("Tab size is " + tabSize);
            if (tabSize == 1) {
                chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='searchPublication']")).click();
                chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/b/b/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/textarea"))
                        .sendKeys("\"" + pubName + "\"");
                chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/b/b/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/input[1]"))
                        .click();
                List<WebElement> paceWithFPN = chromeDriver
                        .findElements(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input[1]"));
                int paceWithFPNSize = paceWithFPN.size();
                if (paceWithFPNSize >= 1) {
                    int paceSubNumber = Integer.parseInt(chromeDriver
                            .findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input[1]"))
                            .getAttribute("value"));

                    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                    cell.setCellValue(paceSubNumber);
                } else {
                    cell.setCellValue("N/A");
                }

            } else {
                cell.setCellValue("N/A");
            }

        }

    }
    chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='searchPublication']")).click();
}
```

Basically there are 2 values used in this program `dBName` and `pubName`
Here what the program does is.

1. enter `dBName` in a text area and get the result and store it in variable `dbPaceNumber.
2. hit on search and again do the same but this time enter `pubName` and store the value in variable `pubPaceNumber`
3. Compare these two variables and see if they are same, if so, enter the result in Excel Cell else concatenate these two values and store it in Excel Cell.

**What is need**

Here in my code the below block is repeated once for `pubName` and once for `dBName`, I want to know if i can make a common block for both and use it. I mean instead of having two block of same code with different data, is there a way that i can make a single block to check once for `pubName` and once for `dBName`.

```
List<WebElement> table = chromeDriver
                        .findElements(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td/b"));
                int tabSize = table.size();
                System.out.println("Tab size is " + tabSize);
                if (tabSize == 1) {
                    chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='searchPublication']")).click();
                    chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/b/b/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/textarea"))
                            .sendKeys("\"" + pubName + "\"");
                    chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/b/b/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/input[1]"))
                            .click();
                    List<WebElement> paceWithFPN = chromeDriver
                            .findElements(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input[1]"));
                    int paceWithFPNSize = paceWithFPN.size();
                    if (paceWithFPNSize >= 1) {
                        int paceSubNumber = Integer.parseInt(chromeDriver
                                .findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input[1]"))
                                .getAttribute("value"));

                        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                        cell.setCellValue(paceSubNumber);
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue("N/A");
                    }

                } else {
                    cell.setCellValue("N/A");
                }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can someone please tell me why there was a down vote, i was not asking for any solution, i was asking for optimization of my code, as the tag says.

Comment: when asking for optimization rather than for bug fixing, codereview.stackexchence.com could be a better place for your question...

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that tip @jkalden, i'll post it there. :-)